# getting data from the backend django models

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project pastly the i used sql querys, but change in the django models
the models i used are
for the members table

```
class Members(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    phoneNo = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length = 50)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

for the bills table

```
salesPerson = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    purchasedPerson = models.ForeignKey(Members, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    cash = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    totalAmount = models.IntegerField()
    advance = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-update', '-created']
```

i am having a query that is

```
credits = Bills.objects.all().filter(cash = False).values ('purchasedPerson').annotate(
        cnt = Count('purchasedPerson'),
        debit = Sum( 'totalAmount' ),
        credit = Sum( 'advance' ),
        balance = Sum( 'totalAmount' ) - Sum( 'advance' )
    ).order_by ('purchasedPerson')
```

getting the output as

```
[{'purchasedPerson': 1, 'cnt': 2, 'debit': 23392, 'credit': 100, 'balance': 23292}, {'purchasedPerson': 2, 'cnt': 1, 'debit': 1280, 'credit': 0, 'balance': 1280}]
```

but i need in the out put name, address and phone number also
how can i get those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass all fields you need in `.values()` like:

```
Bills.objects.filter(cash = False).values('purchasedPerson', 'name', 'address', 'phoneNo').annotate(...)
```

Another choice is skipping the `.values()` part:

```
Bills.objects.filter(cash = False).annotate(...)
```

> **Note:** `all()` is not required in your case.

Comment: `all()` only creates the copy of the original queryset, that's why isn't needed.

Comment: by little modification its works fine by passing the required notations in values part, but if we remove .values the objects are not passing the groupby method. But any way got the answer thanks